# JupyterLab: How attach an python call back function to a button created using Custom Widget?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-console

When, I created a form using the interactive class It's easy to provide a python call-back function, as shown in the example, `My_CallBack_function`, to a click event.

```
from ipywidgets import interactive, widgets

slow = interactive(My_CallBack_function, {'manual': True}, i=widgets.FloatSlider(min=1e4, max=1e6, step=1e4))
```

How to run a python code or python call function 'on click' if form and button are created as a custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

```py
button0 = wg.Button(description='This is button0', tooltip='This is tooltip')
output0 = wg.Output()
display(button0, output0)
def on_button_clicked0(result):
   with output0:
       print('button0 is clicked')
button0.on_click(on_button_clicked0)
```